# Keyboard and Mouse not working

Tags: hardware, keyboard, mouse, compatibility

I am using a Pi Zero, with Raspbian imaged onto the SD card. The OS is showing up on the monitor, but the mouse and keyboard (both AmazonBasics products) just don't work. I am using a 4 port hub to connect the mouse and keyboard; this hub worked on my laptop. Is there any fix to this problem?

Thank you!

Comment: Are you using an OTG adapter between the Pi and hub?

Comment: Something like this https://www.adafruit.com/products/1099 or this https://www.adafruit.com/products/2910

Comment: Also, is your hub externally powered?